# Stacks in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am not sure how to use newtype states in Haskell: So I tried to create a stack that has two states: Active and Inactive, when the stack is active you can do operations on it, when it is Inactive any operations that are done on the stack are automatically ignored. I tried implementing it like:

```
newtype State a = myState [a]
data myState = Active | Inactive
```

Where State a is a myState with a list of items with type of a. But it does not seem to be the correct way to define this? It gives me the following error:

```
Not a data constructor: ‘myState’
```

How would I implement this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A data constructor and type constructor can not have a name that starts with a lowercase, you can define one with:

```
data State a = State MyState [a]
data MyState = Active | Inactive
```

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to set the State from Active to Inactive or if I wanted to add something to the State but keep the MyState the same?

Comment: @chen `myFunction (State x y) = State (change x) y` to change the active state with a user-defined function `change`. Affecting `y` is similarly done.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use either

```
data Stack a = Stack StackState [a]
data StackState = Active | Inactive
```

or

```
data Stack a = ActiveStack [a] | InactiveStack [a]
```

The `Stack`/`ActiveStack`/`InactiveStack` are the constructors for values of the `Stack a` type. Their names, as well as the type names, must be capitalised.